# excel assign sequence to groups within a group

Tags: excel, sequence

i have cases of sequential, character string (rows B & C) data that have been parsed into two categories (rows D & E). assigning sequential order to all data `=ROW(A2)-1` (row I), and for each case `=COUNTIF($A$2:A2, A2)` (row J) is easy enough, but assigning sequential order to *each category* within *each case* has proven difficult.

i have tried combining IFs and SUMPRODUCTS, but struggle to combine them effectively. i would love to avoid dummy coding, which i would like to be directly calculated from the raw data (rows B & C).

here is an example of these data, with the desired results in the final two columns on the right (rows K & L):
[sequential ordering example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lt4oisanqxtd35y/groupOrderingExample.csv?dl=0)

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: Try this in H2 -

```
=COUNTIFS(A$2:A2, A2, B$2:B2, B2)
```

and fill down

Similar for I2

**EDIT2**:

```
=IF(B2<>"",COUNTIFS(A$2:A2,A2,B$2:B2,"<>"),"")
```

Comment: my bad, @tim-williams .. i uploaded an incorrect image. just updated the image to reflect how the sequence numbering for columns H & I resets for each case (ID). thanks for the answer, but hoping you can solve the wrinkle with multiple criteria..?

Comment: how about sequencing if the values in columns B & C are character strings rather than the binary of 1s or blanks?

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: it works great with the dummy coded 1s and blanks, but it recreates the dummy codes (except its 1s and 0s) when i apply it to the character strings that the dummy codes are based on. funny part: if i run that same function again on the new dummy codes, then it sequences both into the same column.

Comment: If your data is different from what you posted then maybe post your actual data?

Comment: thanks for patience and help! updated description above, and swapped out screenshot with .xlsm file with raw data included.

Comment: Typically no-one here (including me, unless I requested it) will download a macro-enabled file: you'd be better off posting a csv or at least xlsx...

Comment: EDIT2 is perfect! thanks for the solution and for teaching me SO etiquette